# XSLT is not working in my JSP

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, web

In my project I need to use [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp) in my JSP to parse XML. Here is my JSP code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
  <h1>Hi, <xsl:value-of select="'welcome user'"/></h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am not getting XSL value here though I have included namespaces.

Do I need to and "xml transformation" in my application? Could anyone check what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT works pretty much by itself on XML (no JSP needed!).  Your code needs to be `<XSL>`, though, not `<HTML>`.  For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
  <h1>Hi, 
  <xsl:value-of select="'welcome user'"/>
  </h1>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope that gets you started!  BTW W3Schools rocks on tutorials http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Comment: Thanks for your information. Il will be helpful if i can write xsl in my jsp file. i used to call have methods and some webservices too. Can i write a xsl in my jsp file? The above one you have mentioned is for client side. What if it is in the server? Please suggest me

Comment: Sure you can use Java's javax.xml.transform package.  Have an example : http://www.ictforu.com/index.php/Core-Java/java-xslt.html

Comment: Thanks..Really that link was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reference to your XSLT file.  You can add a line like this

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="your-xsl-file.xsl"?>
```

Just under the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` line.